# How can I get the history log in Git by developer name?

Tags: git

Assume I use `git shortlog -s -n`. It will show like this

```
   433  Maria Osawa
   199  Sora Aoi
    22  Tsubumi
```

If I want to get only Sora Aoi's history in the Git log, how do I do it?

Comment: `git log --author="Sora Aoi"`

Comment: @TheCodeArtist Thanks sir, sorry about duplicated (: